# Block pool in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I was going through Hadoop tutorials, i got below doubt regarding Block pool in hadoop.

**Block pool- Basically each block pools are managed independently from one another, each one is a set of blocks that belong to a single namespace.**

Is that block pool is virtual concept or is it something like metadat on blocks which is maintained in memory ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is **metadata about each block of data**.

The files in hadoop are divied into blocks and then these blocks are stored on different datanodes. *But to access this data again, we need to know where these blocks are stored*. The namenode does this thing with the help of block pools.

Blockpools are thus metadata about each block of each file on hadoop cluster. They are stored in memory of the namenode and not on disk. So if namenode shuts down, this information needs to be reconstructed.

Now in Hadoop Federation, we have the concept of multiple namespaces. Different namenodes are responsible for different namespaces. Suppose we have two machines acting as namenodes as:

1. Fist namenode (NN1) handles all files under namespace /finance, ie all data of finance department.
2. Similarly second namenode(NN2) handles data of accounts department  under namespace /accounts.

Now to manage the blocks of files under /finance namespace, only NN1 is needed. Thus only NN1 need to have the blockpools of /finance namespace. Similarly to know about files under /accounts we need only NN2. Only NN2 will have block pool of /accounts namespace. Thus they act independently.

Answer (score 1):

Block pools are having the information about each block and each file's data in Hadoop Cluster. Block pools are storing metadata about each blocks in memory, for faster access not on disk. As we all know Hadoop divides each file as sequence of blocks and they are stored on different datanodes. Each block is having definite size i.e in Hadoop 1 block size is 64 MB and in Hadoop 2 we are using block size as 128 MB. If the namenode shutdown or fails in an operation, then whole information is not available to users or administrators in the hadoop cluster.

where does Block pool comes into use in Hadoop ?

Hadoop Federation uses the concept of multiple namespaces. Namespaces are maintained by different namenodes.

Consider the scenario of maintenance of data in an organization of administration, development and other domains. So we have one or multiple namenodes for monitoring the operations done by the users.

In this case we have two namenodes in the hadoop cluster.

First Namenode say NN1 handles all the files come under namespace of /Administration i.e all the data of administration accounts.

Similarly, Second Namenode say NN2 handles all the data of Development accounts under /Development.

Thus, in order to view the blocks of all the files under administration accounts, only the NN1 is needed to view the block pools of /Administration namespace. To view the files under /Development we only need NN2. So these two block pools are independent of each other. Thus they respond independently.

I Hope all who are reading the question understood the concepts clearly.